# Time complexity of Single Link List Insertion and deletion

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I am a bit confused about time complexity of Linked Lists. In this article [here](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) it states that insertion and deletion in a linked list is O(1). I wanted to know how this is possible ? Is it assumed that the forward and next pointers are known ? Wouldn't that  be Double Linked List then ? I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this . And how the time complexity of insertion/deletion of single linked list is O(1) ?

Comment: Add the word *sorted* to that list, and the complexity will quickly ramp. Without caring about "where" insertion is taking place, just jamming something on one end of the list is clearly O(1). Putting something in a *specific* location in the list is O(1) provided you have direct access to the *pointer* that must be directly rewired to the new node (i.e. the insertion point).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it assumed that the forward and next pointers are known ?

In singly linked lists, for both insertion and deletion, you need a pointer to the element *before* the insertion/deletion point. Then everything works out.

For example:

```
# insert y after x in O(1)
def insert_after(x, y): 
    y.next = x.next
    x.next = y

# delete the element after x in O(1)
def delete_after(x):
    x.next = x.next.next
```

For many applications it is easily possible to carry the predecessor of the item you are currently looking at through your algorithm, to allow for dynamic insertion and deletion in constant time. And of course you can always insert and delete at the front of the list in O(1), which allows for a stack-like (LIFO) usage pattern.

Deleting an item when you just know the pointer to the item is generally *not* possible in O(1). **EDIT:** As codebeard demonstrates, we *can* insert and delete by just knowing a pointer to the insertion/deletion point. It involves copying the data from the successor, thus avoiding fixing up the `next` pointer of the predecessor.

Comment: +1 ... last comment, *unless* you have the pointer *by address* (or reference), which is rare, to be sure, but damn handy sometimes. Nice write-up.

Comment: @Rajeshwar I must say that website seems to be kind of confusing seeing as this is the second question of this type today :P Maybe you should use some other resource

Comment: @WhozCraig You mean the predecessor pointer? I thought I mentioned that in the penultimate paragraph

Comment: You may have meant the same thing. I was referring to the actual address of the pointer that points to the target node. Not its value (which obviously is of no use). It may be the address-of the head pointer, or the address of some node's `next` pointer. It doesn't matter which. Its *the thing* that is pointing to the target node. If that as what you meant (and I wish I could uptick this again just for the use of "penultimate") then we're totally on the same page.

Comment: @WhozCraig I see what you mean now.. I don't think it gives you more power than having the predecessor pointer though (a pointer to the "some node" which points to our node), because something could have been inserted between "some node" and our node in the meantime. Now I'm wondering whether it is actually possible to pull this off by inserting not by creating a new node for the inserted element, but by copying its predecessor and reusing its location :P But then maybe we get problems with deletion.. All very weird, but singly linked lists are really cool in any case

Comment: @NiklasB. I agree that some stuff on the mentioned website is really throwing me off. For instance it says that for a BST the worst case scenario of Searching is O(n). I dont agree with this. I am going to look at other resources

Comment: @Rajeshwar Note the difference between binary search tree (which can degenerate to a single chain of nodes, like a list) and *balanced* binary search tree (which has a logarithmically bounded height). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures#Binary_trees) is actually quite useful when it comes to algorithms

Comment: You don't always need to know the element before the insertion point. See my answer.

Comment: @codebeard Now I see what you did there, good point. This requires copying the data around though

Comment: @codebeard Sure, but if you're fine with indirection and additional pointers, you might as well use a doubly linked list. Singly lists are typically used when you want to save space and/or have [persistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure), both of which is not possible if you do it that way. I guess that's why it is not so commonly used, but I don't know

Comment: @NiklasB. The OP's question relates to time complexity, so it doesn't matter what mechanism is used (copying or pointers), it's still O(1).

Comment: @codebeard Sure, sure, you're absolutely right, I just wondered why this is not commonly used since it seems kind of useful. I edited my answer to reflect this fact (hope you don't mind)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's assuming that you already know the place at which you want to insert the data.

Suppose you have some item `p` in the list, and you want to insert a new element `new` after `p` in the list:

```
new->next = p->next;
p->next = new;
```

Alternatively, suppose you want to insert `new` **before** `p`. This can still be done in O(1) time:

```
if (p == head) {
    new->next = head;
    head = new;
} else {
    tmp = p->data;
    p->data = new->data;
    new->data = tmp;
    new->next = p->next;
    p->next = new;
}
```

**As for deleting items in a conventional singly linked list, it's not strictly O(1)!**

It is O(1) for deleting any element except the **last** element. If you are trying to delete the last element in a singly linked list, you need to know the element before it (which requires O(N) time assuming you didn't know it before).

To delete the item `p`:

```
free_if_necessary(p->data);
if (p->next) {
    /* O(1) */
    nextnext = p->next->next;
    nextdata = p->next->data;
    destroy_if_necessary(p->next);
    p->data = nextdata;
    p->next = nextnext;
} else if (p == head) {
    destroy_if_necessary(p);
    head = NULL;
} else {
    /* O(n) */
    prev = find_prev(head, p);
    destroy_if_necessary(p);
    prev->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: @NiklasB. It works fine, because the data pointed to by p is corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is relative to the delete and insert operation for array.

And there is a prerequisite that you know the postion where to insert or delete.

In array, when you want to insert or delete an element at positon `pos`, you should move the other elements after the position `pos`, so the complexity is `O(N)`.

But in List, when you do the same operation, you needn't consider the other elements, so the complexity is `O(1)`.